# Advertised kafka connect rest listener on K8s

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am struggling to setup Kafka Connect on Kubernetes (DockerEE) in distributed mode.
Currently I have a cluster of three workers on three corresponding k8s-pods.
The problem that Im facing is that my workers are having a hard time communicating to each other (at least that is what I belive).

When I try to start a connector I get:

```
{"error_code":409,"message":"Cannot complete request because of a conflicting operation (e.g. worker rebalance)"}
```

in response. The puzzling thing is that I dont always get this error response. Sometimes it work and the connector is started as expected.

From what Ive read it probably comes down to what I have configured as CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME.

What is the correct value to put as advertised address when running in k8s?

BR

Comment: Have you checked through the list of common issues here? https://rmoff.net/2019/11/22/common-mistakes-made-when-configuring-multiple-kafka-connect-workers/

Comment: Now I have - and from what I can tell it basically summarizes and explains my findings (great write up by the way). The question is now what to put there as I'm not sure I can make out the IP of each pod in runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some googling I found a way to dynamically assign the pod-ip as CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME.

```
- name: CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: status.podIP
```

With this the problems seem to have vanished.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Confluent for Kubernetes](https://docs.confluent.io/operator/current/overview.html) and you want to set the `CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` environment variable (to the pod IP), this requires updating the `Connect` resource.

Inside a `Connect` resource, set (or add to) the `spec.podTemplate.envVars` list field (see https://docs.confluent.io/operator/2.6/co-api.html#tag/Connect for fully API reference) as follows:

```
apiVersion: platform.confluent.io/v1beta1
kind: Connect
metadata:
  name: connect-test
spec:
  podTemplate:
    envVars:
      - name: CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: status.podIP
  
  ...
```

Once this is applied to your Kubernetes cluster you can test it by `kubectl exec` into your connect pod:

```bash
kubectl exec -it svc/connect-test -- bash
```

... then running ...

```bash
set | grep CONNECT

    CONNECT_PLUG_PATH=/usr/share/java/,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/
    CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=10.73.12.136       <-------

    ...
```