# Kafka Connect JDBC Source and Sink Connector Part of the Same Plugin

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I've created a JDBC Source and Sink Connector for sending some changes on my Oracle XA Database Table to Kafka and also capture the `Acknowledgement` of the message published to Kafka. Some info regarding the Kafka Connect Plugin I've Deployed :

1. They're deployed in `Distributed Mode`. Works on a Single Pod but failing when I increase pod size to 2.
2. Both Source & Sink Connectors are created on the same Kafka Connect Plugin and running on the same JVM.
3. The Source Connector(`"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector"`) job is to `poll` the DB table(MY_APP_TABLE) on `timestamp` basis with a custom query and send data to Kafka.
4. For now I've set the `batch Size to 500` and `"tasks.max": "2"`for both Source & Sink Connector that I'm gonna change to handle 300 TPS on the DB Table.
5. The Sink Connector(`"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector"`) job is to get the `Acknowledgement` on message published from Kafka. So, once the event is published to Kafka this Sink Connector updates an indicator on the DB table(MY_APP_TABLE) that indicates the specific record has been published to Kafka Topic Successfully.
6. Here are some configurations that's in my `connect-distributed.properties` :

```
group.id=app_data_sync

offset.storage.topic=oracle-connector-offsets-storage
offset.storage.replication.factor=3
offset.storage.partitions=50

config.storage.topic=oracle-connector-config-storage
config.storage.replication.factor=3

status.storage.topic=oracle-connector-status-storage
status.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.partitions=50

listeners=https://0.0.0.0:8443
rest.advertised.listener=https
rest.advertised.host.name=0.0.0.0
rest.advertised.port=8443
```

To Handle about 300 TPS on my DB Table and meet the SLA of 10 mins to have the DB changes relayed to Kafka(with `Exactly-Once-Semantic`) , I'm trying to have at-least 2 Pods(1 Core, 4GB), both running same Source & Sink Connector. **Need Clarification & Suggestion on the following**:

1. Can both Source & Sink Connectors be **created in Distributed mode as part of the same Kafka Connect plugin** and use the **same** **`group.id and offset topic, config topic and status topics`**?
2. Is there a better alternative to capture the **Acknowledgement** of the messages published by Source Connector and have them recorded in the Source DB?
3. Though I've not generated the high TPS, functionally this is working for me with Single Pod. But getting below error with **two pods** : `ERROR IO error forwarding REST request:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient:143) org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectRestException: IO Error trying to forward REST request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem`. Is that related to these configs `rest.advertised.host.name=0.0.0.0 , listeners=https://0.0.0.0:8443`  in my `connect-distributed.properties` ?

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, but yes, all connectors in the same cluster should share the same group and internal topics. You would have to consume the messages written by the source connector in order to write them back to the database as an acknowledgement

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. I think you clarified on Point-2 and Point-1 to some extent. On **Point#1** - The Kafka Connect Plugin is deployed as a JAR on a JVM in Distributed Mode. I'm using this end-point "https://myappconnect.qa.com/connectors" to create both JDBC Source Connector(Producer) & JDBC Sink Connectors(Consumer). So, both Connectors and their Tasks are running on the same JVM, under a single "group.id= app_data_sync" and using the same offset, config & status topics. Is that a valid architecture as both Kafka Producer(Source Connector) and Consumer(Sink Connector) are on the same JVM.

Comment: **Point#3** : For Error ```ERROR IO error forwarding REST request:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient:143)  ``` I'm getting if I increase number of Pods to 2, is that related to these configs ```rest.advertised.host.name=0.0.0.0 , listeners=https://0.0.0.0:8443 ``` in my ```connect-distributed.properties``` ? If yes what should be correct values. Reference : https://rmoff.net/2019/11/22/common-mistakes-made-when-configuring-multiple-kafka-connect-workers/.

Comment: The advertised host name should be the pod service name or an actual resolvable route in the cluster (mistake 2 listed there). 0.0.0.0 is not a routable address, it typically refers to a bind address, such as for the listeners. You'll also need the advertised port to be set if traffic is between multiple pods (8443 is only local https traffic and will need exported outside of the pod). If you're using k8s, I suggest using Strimzi or Confluent Helm Charts rather than maintaining the config on your own

Comment: @jiinxy: Regarding to your [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62136196/advertised-kafka-connect-rest-listener-on-k8s), what would be the `rest.advertised.host.name` for Connectors running in a Distributed mode on a Multi-Pod Connect Cluster ?

Comment: Why can't you use the answer in that question?

Comment: And mentioned before, and if you haven't already, see section 5.5 https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/overview.html

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer - I've Kafka-Connect Cluster running on OpenShift PaaS 3.11. Sorry, I wasn't clear on the reference to [strimzi.io](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/overview.html)
 and CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME as I'm not using strimzi.io. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You don't need to be using Strimzi,, I was only pointing out that it significantly simplifies the problem you're having. The description of the property and the problem it solves still applies - resolving the Connect http server communication between clients. And why can't you use the solution that was provided in the other post you found?

Comment: There were challenges from my Platform Team @OneCricketeer. The issue is still open for us. Appreciate if you could share any other thoughts.

Comment: @bartosz-wardziński - Could you please also share your experience on this?

Comment: I have not used Connect with SSL, but I can say your error is not specific to JDBC or Oracle